# ASP.NET Web API. Роутинг маршрута на файл с разрешением

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Есть URL: `http://localhost/main/cat/sub/file.jsp`

Как сделать роутинг, чтобы при обращении по данному адресу методом `POST` роутило на метод `Post()` в указанном в настройках контроллере?

Мои попытки:

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "Main",
    "main/cat/sub/{*src}",
    new { controller = "Main", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    new { src = @"(.*?)\.(jsp)" }
);
```

**MainController.cs**

```
public class MainController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri]RequestModel values)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

В данном случае получаю `404`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.
В `Web.config` необходимо добавить `handler` c указанием расширения файла:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="JspFileHandler" path="*.jsp" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```